# Querying for subsets in CloudSearch literal-array

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

My index has a literal-array field `foo` and I want to search for documents whose `foo` is a subset of the values specified in a query.

For example, consider this index and a query for `{A, B, D}`:

```
doc1: foo=[A, B] --> returned bc {A,B} is a subset of query {A, B, D}
doc2: foo=[A, B, C] --> excluded bc C is not a member of {A, B, D}
```

Is it possible to construct such a query?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @alexroussos Is it possible to do a exact match for searching an element of literal array?

Comment: @P.Prasad yes it is